# "he does fear which humans could be in control."

Tags: conjunctions, interrogatives

This is from [a news article](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/openai-ceo-sam-altman-ai-reshape-society-acknowledges/story?id=97897122).

> A common sci-fi fear that Altman doesn't share: AI models that don't
> need humans, that make their own decisions and plot world domination.
>
> "It waits for someone to give it an input," Altman said. "This is a
> tool that is very much in human control."
>
> However, he said he does fear **which** humans could be in control. "There
> will be other people who don't put some of the safety limits that we
> put on," he added. "Society, I think, has a limited amount of time to
> figure out how to react to that, how to regulate that, how to handle
> it."

I think "which" in bold should be replaced with a conjunction "that".

Am I wrong?

Comment: No, it doesn't. "What he _is_ worried about is [the question of] which human beings could be in control" - it might be ones who use AI irresponsibly.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, *which* doesn't mean *that* here.

He is concerned about the question "Which humans could be in control?", and fears some of the possible answers.